# How to make a QIcon clickable?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

**Goal**

I want the user to be able to click on a QIcon to do something. That is, I want to connect a mouse click event, within a QIcon, to a slot.

**What I have tried**

In my example (below) I am using a tree view, and when the user clicks one of the icons, I want to add a child to that node.

I have tried doing this by reimplementing `mousePressEvent` for the icon, but I'm not sure how to do so for icons (which by default serve a purely decorator role) within a treeviewmodel.

The code, in simplified form, is as below:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import icons_rc

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, parentNode=None):
        self.name = name
        self.childNodes = []  
        self.parentNode = parentNode
        if parentNode is not None:  #if self has a parent, then add self node to parent in tree
            parentNode.addChild(self)

    def addChild(self, childNode):
        self.childNodes.append(childNode)  #

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def data(self):
        return self.name

    def child(self, row):
        return self.childNodes[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.childNodes)

    def parent(self):
        return self.parentNode

    def row(self):
        if self.parentNode is not None: #if self has a parent, then return  row of self
            return self.parentNode.childNodes.index(self)


class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    #Inputs: node, Qobject
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rootNode = root

    def rowCount(self, parentIndex=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parentIndex.isValid():
            parentNode = self.rootNode
        else:
            parentNode = parentIndex.internalPointer()  #picks out parent node of tree
        return parentNode.childCount()

    def columnCount(self, parentIndex=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def flags(self,index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        node=index.internalPointer()
        #role--editrole here so text doesn't disappear when you double click
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return node.data()  #node.data method defined above (string)

        #icons are shown by using a decoration role
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/add.png"))

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            return  True
        else:
            return False

    def getNode(self,index):
        if index.isValid():
            node=index.internalPointer()
            if node:
                return node
        return self.rootNode

    def parent(self, childIndex):
        if not childIndex.isValid(): 
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        childNode = self.getNode(childIndex) 
        parentNode = childNode.parent()  
        if parentNode == self.rootNode:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        return self.createIndex(parentNode.row(), 0, parentNode)

    def index(self, row, column, parentIndex):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parentIndex):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        parentNode=self.getNode(parentIndex)
        childNode = parentNode.child(row)  #implemented above
        if childNode:
            return self.createIndex(row, 0, childNode) #row/col/object yields index
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()


def main():
    import sys
    qtApp=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    rootNode = Node("Hips")  #for some reason, by design, this will not show
    childNode0 = Node("LeftLeg", rootNode)
    childNode1 = Node("RightLeg", rootNode)
    childNode2 = Node("RightAnkle", childNode1)
    childNode3 = Node("Middle toe", childNode2)
    childNode4 = Node("Pirate flank toe", childNode2)
    childNode5 = Node("Pinky toe", childNode2)

    model=TreeModel(rootNode)
    treeView = QtGui.QTreeView()
    treeView.show()  #opens empty window
    treeView.setModel(model)

    sys.exit(qtApp.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Basically I want to build an event handler that adds a child when I click an icon, an icon which is given in add.png. Is there some sneaky route to reimplement `mouseClickEvent` or other functions for icons? I have made zero headway on this problem with Google.

I tried subclassing QIcon, and reimplementing mousePressEvent. The goal is to use this revised icon class within TreeModel.data(). So far I have had no luck getting the class to work. Here's what I tried:

```
class ClickableQIcon(QtGui.QIcon):

    def __init__(self, iconPixmap, parent):
        QtGui.QIcon.__init__(self, iconPixmap, parent)      

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "This time you pressed in an icon"
```

Where I would feed it something like `iconPixmap=QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/add.png"))` as one of the inputs in the calling function. It doesn't work, I only include it to show the kind of solution I was hoping to find.

**Potentially relevant posts:**

[Button Icon Change on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353065/button-icon-change-on-click)

[QIcon inside combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389013/qicon-inside-combobox)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reimplement event handlers for `QIcon` because it's a simple container for an image and has nothing to do with event handling. That's why your extended `QIcon` class didn't do anything.

Also `QTreeView` by default only draws icons for decorations.

You could use a custom item delegate in your tree view.
`QTreeView` inherits from `QAbstractItemView` which has several `setItemDelegate` methods ([documentation](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html)). Then either extend `QItemDelegate` or implement `QAbstractItemDelegate`.

A bit faster might be to set custom widgets with `setIndexWidget()`.

In case the icon is always the same you might even get away with a stylesheet on the `QTreeView`. ([documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview))

Comment: a bit similar is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175333/howto-create-delegate-for-qtreewidget

Comment: setIndexWidget should work: probably no need to mess with custom delegates if you don't want to. Asked about setting custom widgets in a list here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199374/add-qwidget-to-qlistwidget . It should be similar for a tree.

Comment: is it possible to change it from its default decorator role to another role, and then make it clickable?